# Response handling of an AJAX GET request without data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, response

I'm stuck on something rather simple. I have a simple AJAX GET request function that I need to work on the response handling. It doesn't have any data sent out with it, the data is simply handled through the GET url. Unfortunately, I've never sent out without the data and while my responses are successful in bringing back a JSON response, it doesn't do anything that should be done if the response doesn't have any errors.

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#pullDetails', function() {
            $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'https://webservices.rrts.com/TrackWebApi/api/values/'+$('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
            success: function(response) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((response.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            toastr.error('Validation error - Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                            $('#carrierReturnData').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('#carrierReturnData').html(Shipment.Origin.Name);


                    }
                },
            });
        });
</script>
```

Specifically, underneath the ELSE near the bottom, the remove class doesn't work so I know that the script must be thinking an error is occurring....

The response data (some of it is as such):

```
SearchResults   […]
   0    {…}
    SearchItem  ----9
    DisplayType 0
    Shipment    {…}
       DRAvail  false
       ProNumber    -----9
       PickupNumber Not Found
       CustomerNumber   ----3
       BillToAccount    ----34
```

### Update

[image]

### Update

[image]

### Update

[image]

Comment: What is the _specific_ value of `response`, when it comes back from your response handler?  Do you have errors in your brower's developer console? Are you sure your response handler is being triggered?

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific with the following condition - `response.errors` - since code in `else` statement isn't being executed. As @cale_b pointed out, it would be helpful to see the value of `response`.

Comment: I have updated with the response that I receive from the GET. However, I should've pointed out that I'm not sure what to put where the response is. Usually I just have data.errors from my past encounters with AJAX, but this doesn't have the "data" being sent out.

Comment: I still don't see `errors` defined in your response.

Comment: Right, and I doubt I would see any errors at all, but my issue is how would I integrate in response errors to this particular GET response.

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting to handle form specific errors that are set on the server-side or "generic" request errors?

Comment: Just generic request errors. At the moment, while you can see the returned data, the success isn't being triggered at all. I've widdled everything down to a simple alert message in the success return but nothing happens, so I'm assuming that my script thinks the response isn't actually successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments. You can handle ajax request errors as such.

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'https://webservices.rrts.com/TrackWebApi/api/values/'+$('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
    success: function(response) {
        $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
        $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

        $('#carrierReturnData').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#carrierReturnData').html(Shipment.Origin.Name);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        // Do stuff with the errors
    }
});
```

For reference, [jQuery `$ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I've used your suggestion, and for ease I added "alert('hello!');" where the do stuff with errors is. Unfortunately, while I get a successful response, it alerted me to "hello!" which means that it still thinks the response (as seen above in my question) is an error...

Comment: Try outputting the returned data: request, error, etc.

Comment: alert(request); - returns [object Object], alert(status); returns "error" and alert(error); - returns blank

Comment: Log it to the console, so you can actually look at the contents.

Comment: See my updates to my question above. I've never seen a response like this so I'd appreciate any thoughts...

Comment: oh and that's being returned using:               console.log(request);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);

Comment: I've added to the question with the screenshot of the expanded error.

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion to handle the errors I was referring to and handle the returned data through another method.